# Need help identifying Industry Nine part

Tags: wheels, parts, hub

I recently picked up a box-lot of Industry Nine parts, including the items pictured. They are 92mm wide, and of varying diameters. Could someone please tell me what they are, and what they are used for?

Thanks very much,
Norm

[image: Industry Nine parts]

Comment: 'picked up' meaning? :-/

Comment: Lot won at a local auction.

Answer (score 4):

Flangeless front hub shells.

Standard OLD for front hubs is 100mm - which these would be with bearings and axle installed.

The array of holes at each end are for attaching spokes.